# Initializing combobox with VBA when Excel sheet is loaded

Tags: excel, vba

I am using MS Excel 2016. I added ComboBox(ActivexControl) to Sheet1.

I want to add values to the Combobox while the worksheet is opening.

I tried following.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Open()
    With Sheet1.ComboBox4
        .AddItem "File to Table"
        .AddItem "Table to File"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Workbook_Open() instead of Worksheet_open()

Comment: thank you for your comment.I tried it.But still it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure

- your Sheetcode name is Sheet1
- Your ComboBox is named ComboBox4
- The code is placed in the ThisWorkbook codemodule/section, not in the    section of the sheet
- Use Workbook_open() instead of Worksheet_Open()